# Where can I give feedback for YouTube Video Editor?

Tags: youtube

Where can I give my product feedback for the YouTube Video Editor that provides the interface shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://www.youtube.com/ and click the `Send feedback` link on the bottom.